# Develop a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json

I have to update a url using chrome extension.
**Here is my manifest file**

```
{
    "name": "My First Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "The first extension that I made.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "cwins.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
    "http://www.google.co.in/",
    "http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&biw=1920&bih=955&q=anushka&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&fp=5f42a1c1d2fc35ec"   
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://www.google.co.in/"],      
            "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**here is my content_scripts (myscripts.js)**

```
alert('hi');

chrome.tabs.getSelected({}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
        url: 'http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&biw=1920&bih=955&q=anushka&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&fp=5f42a1c1d2fc35ec'
    });
});

alert('bye');
```

ITS NOT UPDATING THE URL

Comment: Sorry to be harsh but: 1) Bad title 2) Bad formatting 3) Not a specific question.

Comment: I have gone through and cleaned up the code formatting for them but the edit needs to be approved. Still, I agree, we need a lot more information to help with this.

Comment: @Wolfy87 - good on you. I started to edit but gave up :)

Comment: Actually the extension should work as follows..whenever it see "http://www.google.co.in/", the extension should update the URL to http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&biw=1920 and navigate to this page. this should be done automatically by the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple issues: you can't access `chrome.tabs` in a content script, and `chrome.tabs.getSelected` requires the "tabs" permission.

Setting `window.location` *should* work in the content script though, so if that's all you need to do, myscripts.js could be as simple as:

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&biw=1920...';
```

If you do need to use `chrome.tabs.update`, you can access it from a background page. Basically, you would need to set up an `onRequest` event handler in the background page, and send a request using `chrome.extension.sendRequest` from the content script.

So basically you'd have this for your content script (myscript.js):

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({ url: 'http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en...' });
```

and your background page would have a script element with something like this:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, { url: request.url });
});
```

Comment: window.location will open the mentioned URL in new window. But I want the current page should get refreshed with the http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&biw=1920... automatically using chrome.tabs.update/ some other function. Thanks in advance
-

Comment: When I tried it, it worked fine. I'll update the answer to show basically how to do it with `chrome.tabs.*` though, in case you need to do it that way.